# Why do for-each-ref and show-ref behave differently in a bare repository?

Tags: git

In a standard (non-bare) Git repository the following commands all give essentially the same result, in that they list all the branches (the number after each command is the output of the command piped into `wc -l` just to keep things brief):

```
R1) bare: false
    pwd                           .../R1/.git
    git branch                    8
    git for-each-ref refs/heads   8
    git show-ref --heads          8
    git for-each-ref refs/heads/* 8
    git show-ref refs/heads/*     8
    find ./refs/heads -type f     8
```

but in a bare repository the same is not apparently always true:

```
R2) bare: true
    pwd                           .../R2.git
    git branch                    24
    git for-each-ref refs/heads   24
    git show-ref --heads          24
    git for-each-ref refs/heads/* 17
    git show-ref refs/heads/*     13
    find ./refs/heads -type f     14
R3) bare: true
    pwd                           .../R3.git
    git branch                    15
    git for-each-ref refs/heads   15
    git show-ref --heads          15
    git for-each-ref refs/heads/* 6
    git show-ref refs/heads/*     6
    find ./refs/heads -type f     6
R4) bare: true
    pwd                           .../R4.git
    git branch                    36
    git for-each-ref refs/heads   36
    git show-ref --heads          36
    git for-each-ref refs/heads/* 36
    git show-ref refs/heads/*     0
    find ./refs/heads -type f     0
```

So from reviewing a lot more repositories than shown here, the first 3 commands always give consistent answers, bare or non-bare, but the last 3 give results that are not always the same as the first three, and not always consistent with each other. Can someone explain why?

From working with non-bare repositories I've always assumed commands like `branch`, `show-ref` and `for-each-ref` work on the actual contents of refs/heads directory, but in the bare case this can't be true, because they show more results than there are files in the refs/heads directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*short answer :*

Suppress the shell`s wildcard handling by quoting the arguments :

```
git for-each-ref "refs/heads/*"
```

and run your commands again.

Because of `packed-refs`, `find` will not (or rarely) give you the correct answer.

---

*detailed answer :*

There several issues with your commands:

1. The most important first: Git has *two* places to store refs (i.e. tags, branches, ...): the `.git/refs` directory AND the file `.git/packed-refs`. See [git-pack-refs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pack-refs) for details.

   This rules out `find ./refs/heads -type f` for getting correct answers.
2. The next **two** things: These command do not what you think they do:

   ```
   git for-each-ref refs/heads/*
   git show-ref refs/heads/*
   ```

   Assuming a Unix-like environment the **shell** tries to expand the `*` wildcard by matching existing filenames. So `git` sees actually a command like this:

   ```
   git for-each-ref refs/heads/master refs/heads/topic1
   ```

   So whenever a ref is stored *only* in the `packed-refs` file then the shell will not pass that name to `git` and hence there is no output.

   The second issue with wildcard matching: The shell does *not* recurse into subdirectories, so a branch `feature/foo` will not show up even when the ref is stored in `.git/refs/heads/feature/foo`.

   You could suppress the shell`s wildcard handling by quoting the arguments. There are several ways to do so, a simple way is this:

   ```
   git for-each-ref "refs/heads/*"
   ```

The difference is not really between bare and non-bare repositories but between "shell sees at least one match" and "the shell sees no match at all" because in the later case the shell forwards the string as is (including the `*`) to the command. In a non-bare repo this is the case because the `.git/` prefix is missing in your arguments.